# Make Default Buttons Look Like Normal Buttons

Tags: css, button, javafx, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX button that has been set as *Default Button* so the user can select it with the Enter key. Currently, it has a blue background:

[image]

But I'd like to make it look like a normal button:

[image]

I took a look at the JavaFX CSS Guide and it looks like there's only one feature to override (`-fx-base`).

[image]

But changing this feature has unpredictable effects—sometimes it eliminates the button's gradient; sometimes it makes the button transparent.

**Is there a simple way to just get rid of the *Default Button* styling?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you are looking in the wrong style sheet. The old default style sheet caspian.css was replaced with modena.css. So setting default value for `-fx-base` from modena.css should fix the issue:

```
.button:default {
    -fx-base: #ececec;
}
```

Comment: Ah you got me! I was looking at Caspian. Thanks a lot!